# How to extract/convert hundreds of .mov files into PNG image files,automatically creating a folder for each group of PNG files extracted

Tags: video, ffmpeg, batch-file, png

I need to batch extract and convert hundreds of .mov files into PNG image files, automatically creating a folder for each group of PNG files extracted. (I’m working on Windows 10). Can you suggest to me how to modify the code that I've written ? Thanks.

```
@echo off
for file in *.mov; do echo ffmpeg -i "$file" -vf "select=gte(n\,300)" -vframes 1 "${file%.mov}.png"; done
pause
```

it produces the following error : **not expected file**

You can find one of the hundreds files that I'm trying to convert,[here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ttMdw9AjkUP1VTV-k2LTDD-CrHBjNpER).

UPDATE : I created this and it works.

```
    pushd %1

if not exist newfiles\ (
mkdir newfiles
)

if not exist newfiles2\ (
mkdir newfiles2
)

:start

for %%F in (*.mov) do (
    md "%%~nF"
    echo "%%~nF"
    ffmpeg -i %%F -r 1 -f image2 -qscale:v 2 "%%~nF\%%~nF_image-%%3d.png"
    copy "%%~nF\%%~nF_image-001.png" ".\newfiles" 
    )
popd
```

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill remove the "put on hold" thing. I have edited the question.

Comment: @Marietto The community has to vote on this for it to be reopened but it seems like you dropped Linux code and trying to run it as Windows commands.Read over https://ss64.com/nt/for.html and consider trying to make it more Windows compatible like `for %a in (*.mov) do echo ffmpeg -i "%~a" -vf "select=gte(n\,300)" -vframes 1 "%~Na.png"` for example or some variation like that. Then [edit] and put the Windows commands and whatever error you get. I have no clue if that is an accurate command or not as I did not test, just giving you a simple 20 second worth of typing starting point only.

Comment: And, if you don’t know how to make a directory,  you need to do some basic research.